# Should minor links be styled with the same hover effects as primary links?

Tags: interaction-design, hyperlinks, hover

I have the following article which has a primary title link as well as breadcrumb and social links.

Should I use the primary links' hover effect style for the breadcrumb and social links or differentiate the priority by using a lighter rollover colour?

Ideally I'd like to use a different colour but I'm wondering if that is a big UX no no.

Normal state


[image]

Active state with all links in active state

[image]

Comment: The bigger no-no here is having links with no visual affordance at all (they're styled without any underlines and no colour cues).

Comment: True,additionally remember hover is becoming obsolete with touch interfaces!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The share and save links are fine because:

- Icons/Buttons alongside text.
- Knowledge of word meaning and standardised placement of links makes it an intuitive location to put them.
- Good colours away from the standard text colours of the page.

Why the heading for the 'element' is not so good:

- Same colour, styles (and size?) as the top header `Image collections`
- The colour, to me, on my work screen is hard to read with said style.

Move away from the `Image collections` follow style and try bring in something a bit thicker or bolder than the two buttons below *and* the main header.

Comment: Hi, good point about the heading text, I'll bump up the font weight there, I agree that orange isn't great but it's the brand colour.